# node option: making it quite when an error is thrown

Tags: node.js

is there a node cli option that lets it not print an error?

For example, I'd like the command below not to print an uncaught exception, even if it occurs. But I don't simply want to catch it in the code. If there's no exception or error, then it should print (if message to print exists) what it's intended to.

```sh
$ node --quiet-on-err(?) this-script-throws-err.js
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) (assuming you're using a platform that has /dev/null): `node this-script-throws-err.js 2/>dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks :) But you might misunderstand what I mentioned. Redirection to /dev/null just throws away the output no matter whether it's by uncaught exception. I want the process to print normal(not by exception) messages. If there's an exception or error, I want the process not to print message by exception.

Comment: Redirecting only `2` to /dev/null might do what you're looking for. For example if you have a file that has `console.log('hi'); throw new Error('oh no')` and run it with `node thing.js 2>/dev/null`, it will still print `hi`, but not the error. I'm not sure of a way to only handle uncaughtexceptions though, rather than all errors.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't catching all uncaught exception work for you? Add this to the code. This is a process wide event handler that gets called whenever an uncaught exception is found.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (exception) => {
  // handle or ignore error
});
```

Comment: Thanks :)
But you might misunderstand what I mentioned.
Due to special reason, I don't want to catch an uncaught exception in the code.
That's why I'm looking for something like a cli option for workaround (but it doesn't have to be cli option).

Comment: @jjangga I am not sure there's any other options other than to use this. Usually when we get an uncaught exception it means there are some error cases to be caught and requires a rewrite. Even using this approach is not advisable, but I posted it so it might satisfy your requirement. Anyway please post an answer if you get one.